# How can a sum multiple values from the same key across different dictionaries in swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, sum

I am new to Swift and iOS dev. in general. I was wondering how I could sum multiple values from the same key across different dictionaries. e.g. I have

20 dictionaries with the same key value pair [String: AnyObject] e.g. "Height": 20 I want to sum these and calculate the average.
 EG:

```
// Example dictionary 
let player17: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "Name": "Les Clay",
    "Height": 42,
    "Soccer Experience": true,
    "Guardian Name(s)": "Wynonna Brown"
]
```

//Used any object here as they all go into a big array

Comment: Are your 20 dictionaries, in themselves, contained within some container? If you want to do common work with data contained in different dictionaries, possibly nest your dictionaries into a single dictionary or array. Also, as an alternative to using a `String: AnyObject` dict., given that the different _types_ of player data is somewhat static (known at compile time), consider defining your player data as instance members of a `struct` (hence not needing to work with `AnyObject`).

Comment: Yes forgot to sat they are all in an array called allPlayers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to add numbers up, like this:

```
let totalHeight = allPlayers.reduce(0) { (p, c) -> Int in
    return p + (c["Height"] as! Int)
}
```

**Note:** The `c["Height"] as! Int` approach requires hard knowledge that `"Height"` key is present in every dictionary, and its value is of type `Int`. Otherwise, this will produce an exception at run time.

If some of your dictionaries do not have the proper key in them, or contain the value of a different type, you need to pre-filter or use an optional cast, for example

```
return p + ((c["Height"] as? Int) ?? 0)
```

Comment: @dfri Just tries this in playground, works like a charm.

Comment: @dfri Here is a [link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mzTtTprc) if you'd like to try it out.

Comment: @dfri: That is because your array contains an *empty dictionary* for which `c["Height"] == nil`.

Comment: *Numbers* are bridged to `Int` automatically. But this would crash if `c["Height"]` is – for example – a string (or non-existent)

Comment: @MartinR Ah of course, ouch, thanks! dasblinkenlight: my bad then! But I would still recommend something along the lines `return p + ((c["Height"] as? Int) ?? 0)` rather than using `as!`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
let players: [[String:AnyObject]] = ...
```

here's another approach

```
let sum = players.flatMap { $0["Height"] as? Int }.reduce(0, combine: +)
```

> If a dictionary doesn't have a valid `Int` value for the `"Height"` key then that dictionary is ignored.